# JOLT transformation remove a specific field

Tags: json, jolt

Edit1: My goal is to be able to remove a specific attribute that has a specific value. In my example, the rating attribute should be removed as soon as it has a "?" as content.
"rating": "?" => should be deleted
"rating": "1" => should NOT be deleted

Hi all, is there any way that I don't remove all attributes of a certain type, but only those that have a certain content? Example:
"test1": "123",
"test1":"?"

Here I would like to remove only test1:"?".

***Input***:

```json
{
  "TEST": {
    "revision": "2021",
    "results": [
      {
        "parameter": "Abweichung X L/R",
        "example": "123",
        "rating": "1"
      },
      {
        "parameter": "10001",
        "example": "BIN7934659050003696",
        "rating": "?"
      },
      {
        "parameter": "1015 Bauteil niO",
        "rating": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

***Desired Output***:

```json
{
  "TEST": {
    "revision": "2021",
    "results": [
      {
        "parameter": "Test",
        "example": "123456",
        "rating": "1"
      },
      {
        "parameter": "10001",
        "example": "123"
      },
      {
        "parameter": "Test123",
        "rating": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

All "ratings" except the one with the content "?" remain.

Thanks in advance and many greetings

Comment: My goal is to be able to remove a specific attribute that has a specific value. In my example, the rating attribute should be removed as soon as it has a "?" as content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below **shift** transformation spec in order to remove the attribute **rating** with value **?**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "TEST": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "results": {
          "*": {
            "rating": {
              "?": {
                "@(2,parameter)": "&5.&4.[&3].parameter",
                "@(2,example)": "&5.&4.[&3].example"
              },
              "*": {
                "@2": "&5.&4.[&3]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

**"*"** represents the rest of the keys(***revision*** in this case) other than specified(***results***)

the **&1** at the top and **&5**s represent the outermost key(***TEST***)

the **&4**s represent the array's(***results***) name

the **[&3]** s are needed to combine the independent sub-elements due to the indexes of the array(***results***) as a common center